# Rails 3 - Store and Access large amount of static data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails 3 app that uses Geocoder for a search feature that I'm building.  I need to be able to access a table (or hash) of static latitude/longitude data for all US airports.  I currently have the data, but I need to store it somehow so that it is accessible.

Possible Solution 1:
I know that I can store a "static" hash of key/value pairs in a Helper to be called on like this:

```
AIRPORTS = { "abc" => "30.33, -95.66", "efg" => "42.65, -96.72", ... }
```

But the data contains about 20K key/value pairs.  Wouldn't this all get pulled into memory and slow things down OR break?

Possible Solution 2:
Is there a way to store 20K+ static key/value pairs in a database table?  I would think that there is, but I have only worked with dynamic data thus far.

Any help or additional suggestions would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance.